# How to see the whole question that is used in the tour of the site?

Tags: bug, tour

Prompted by [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20793/choice-of-the-question-in-the-tour?cb=1) I clicked through to see what was going on.  I got to this [tour page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) but I couldn't see the whole question or the answers.  I clicked everywhere I could think of, but nothing took me to the question in question.

Answer (score 3):

I think the links to the question are intentionally disabled in the tour. Consider that every new user is invited to take the tour and some of them already have enough reputation to upvote, thanks to the association bonus. Bringing extra traffic to a randomly chosen example question is likely to distort voting there, and/or add noise in the form of non-answers.

One can still locate the question by copying a part of its text and putting it in the search box. Here is the current example question:  [Prove that $A_{100} \gt 14$ where $A_{n}=A_{n-1}+\frac{1}{A_{n-1}}$ and $A_1=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338736/prove-that-a-100-gt-14-where-a-n-a-n-1-frac1a-n-1-and-a-1-1)

Also on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251792/):

> There is no point to make it a real link; that's just an example. In fact, even votes and favourites don't match, and in the real question, another answer is accepted.